# ConcurrentModificationException with Android and OpenGL ES 1.1

Tags: android, opengl-es, concurrency

I'm pretty new to OpenGL programming, and I made a simple engine to simplify my drawings, which worked. Now I want to make transformations based on the accelerometer, and I'm getting a *ConcurrentModificationException*.

Here's the object class:

```
public class IbnRushdObject
{
    /** The graphical object to show */
    private Mesh mesh = null;

    /** List of transformations to be executed upon this object */
    private List<IbnRushdTransformation> transformations;

    /** Lock to prevent modification of the list when executing the transformations and viceversa */
    private final ReentrantLock lock = new ReentrantLock();

    /**
     * Initializes this IbnRushd object with a mesh
     * @param mesh
     */
    public IbnRushdObject(Mesh mesh)
    {
        this.mesh = mesh;
    }

    /**
     * Adds a transformation to be performed on this object<br>
     * The transformation does not take place until {@link #moveDraw(GL10)} is called
     * @param trans
     */
    public void addTransformation(IbnRushdTransformation trans)
    {
        try
        {
            lock.lock();
            if (transformations == null)
            {
                transformations = new LinkedList<IbnRushdTransformation>();         
            }
            transformations.add(trans);
        }
        finally
        {
            lock.unlock();
        }
    }

    /**
     * Executes transformations for this object and draws it
     * @param gl
     */
    public void moveDraw(GL10 gl)
    {
        gl.glMatrixMode(GL10.GL_MODELVIEW);
        gl.glLoadIdentity();

        try
        {
            lock.lock();
            for(IbnRushdTransformation trans: transformations) // ConcurrentMoificationException thrown here
            {
                trans.execute(gl);
                if (!trans.isPermanent())
                {
                    transformations.remove(trans);
                }
            }
        }
        finally
        {
            lock.unlock();
        }

        gl.glEnableClientState(GL10.GL_VERTEX_ARRAY);
        gl.glEnableClientState(GL10.GL_COLOR_ARRAY);

        mesh.draw(gl);
    }
}
```

And the *moveDraw()* method is only called from

```
@Override
public void onDrawFrame(GL10 gl)
{
    gl.glClear(GL10.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL10.GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);
    gl.glClearColor(0, 0.5f, 0.5f, 1.0f);

    for(IbnRushdObject object : objectQueue)
    {
        object.moveDraw(gl);
    }
}
```

which holds a list of all object to be drawn.

This is the code that listens to accelerometer events. The listener method is *onEventChange()*.

```
public class IbnRushdOrientation implements ServiceListener<Orientation>
{
    private IbnRushdObject object = null;

    public IbnRushdOrientation(IbnRushdObject obj)
    {
        object = obj;
    }

    @Override
    public void onEventChange(Orientation arg0)
    {
        IbnRushdRotation hrot = new IbnRushdRotation();
        hrot.setFixed(0, 0, 1, 0);
        hrot.setIncremental((float)arg0.getHorizontalAngle());
        hrot.setPermanent(false);

        IbnRushdRotation vrot = new IbnRushdRotation();
        vrot.setFixed(0, 1, 0, 0);
        vrot.setIncremental((float)arg0.getVerticalAngle());
        vrot.setPermanent(false);

        object.addTransformation(hrot);
        object.addTransformation(vrot);
    }
}
```

I get the ConcurrentModificationException on `for(IbnRushdTransformation trans: transformations)` in *moveDraw()* method.

Any ideas? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't remove an object from your list as you're iterating over it. That's what's causing the exception.

If you iterated the list using an iterator instead of a for loop (transformations.iterator()) then you can call iterator.remove() to safely remove it while iterating over.

"Note that Iterator.remove is the only safe way to modify a collection during iteration; the behavior is unspecified if the underlying collection is modified in any other way while the iteration is in progress."

http://java.sun.com/docs/books/tutorial/collections/interfaces/collection.html